# "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" after update to ADT 14

Tags: android, exception, adt, dalvik, android-library

After updating to the latest developer tools, ADT 14, my Android project that includes library projects will no longer run producing the error:

```
Dx UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: ... already added: ...
...
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

The other threads describing this issue with solutions that include removing and re-adding the projects do not work.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the answer yet, but the solution (per the [Android Tools Project Site known issues](http://tools.android.com/knownissues)) is to remove the `<libraryname>_src` source folders from your projects. You can do this by right clicking them and choose "Build Path -> Remove from Build Path" or in your project properties (Java Build Path -> Source tab).

Comment: ashughes: I followed your advice, but then I get build errors in my main project, saying that it cannot resolve [library proj] to a type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem is listed as a [known issue](http://tools.android.com/knownissues) of ADT 14. Here's the quote from the Android Tools Project Site:

> Project not building with error
>   `[2011-10-20 23:32:04 - MyApp] Dx UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:<class>: already added: <class>`
>   This is due to a failure to remove previous library source folders from the
>   main project. Incidentally, the fragility around those linked source
>   folders is one of the reason we are moving away from this mechanism
>   (see more info at
>   http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14). The
>   solution is to remove those `<libraryname>_src` source folders from
>   your projects. Just right click them and choose `Build Path > Remove
>   from Build Path`. You should also be prompted to remove the linked
>   folder which you should do. If you're not prompted, remove it
>   manually. You can see some screenshot of the problem in this great
>   post:
>   http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/fix-the-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-with-adt-14

**Solution:**

As it says, the solution is to remove the `<libraryname>_src` source folders from your projects. You can do this by right clicking them and choose "Build Path -> Remove from Build Path" or in your project properties (Java Build Path -> Source tab).

Comment: Sorry to those of you who answered my question already. I was posting the question and solution to help others find this issue regarding ADT 14 easier (since other questions were asked prior to ADT 14 being released), but I couldn't post my answer right away because I didn't have over 100 rep. I wanted to include more info like the quote from the Android Tools Project site.

Comment: Google published a blog post describing the changes to Library Projects in ADT 14: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html

Answer (score 6):

I also ran into this problem, but none of the above fixed it:

- Tried removing/re-adding libraries with clean builds along the way
- Tried deleting and re-importing projects

No dice. Still the "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" was staring me in the face every time I tried to export to an apk.

I could tell the problem was related to ProGuard, because when I commented out this line in my *project.properties* file, everything worked fine:

```
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

However, I wasn't able to solve the problem until I found [this post by David M Young](http://davematthew.blogspot.com/2011/10/compiling-with-android-adt-14.html). Apparently, ADK/ADT 14 shipped with an incorrect version of ProGuard (oops!). I downloaded  [ProGuard version 4.6](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard/). Replaced the *android-sdk*\android-sdk\tools\proguard\lib directory contents with *proguard4.6.zip*\proguard4.6\lib (3 *.jar files), restarted Eclipse and export to apk worked again!

Answer (score 5):

To solve you should:

- Right click on your project>Properties>Java Build Path and remove all libs but the one Android I.J (depending on your version)
- Project>Clean
- Add back the libs you've removed

If the problem comes back another times it's useful to put the libs outside your project and import them as "External JARs"

Comment: Thanks, I tried a bunch of different solutions but this one finally sorted it out for me.

Answer (score 1):

Hello thought I'd throw my two cents in here. as I did do that,

"_src -> Remove from path"

Then I cleaned it and rebuilt and I could get it to run in debug mode on my phone just fine. I could also export it; but only if I disabled proguard. of course I couldn't leave it like that with my code open for all to see. so it was quite madding. but I Finally found a cure, oddly enough they had the same problem (and fix) with r12 as they do with this one.

it's in: [Android SDK Installation Directory]\tools\proguard\bin\proguard.bat

Change

call %java_exe% -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %*

to

call %java_exe% -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9

I tried tons of other stuff but this is what did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with the android sdk. Check out this [blogpost](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/fix-the-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-with-adt-14) for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I used a library for my project and had the same error - it was solved by removing library and src-folder, cleaning and adding it back and cleaned again.

Remove

1. Project properties -> Android: Remove libs, 'Apply'
2. Remove included library src-folder
3. better clean,

Add again

1. Project properties -> Android: Add libs again, 'Apply'
2. Clean project

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem come back again (fixed first time by removing the _src items as mentioned in other answers) - this time there were no _src files to remove. The error was relating the android-support-v4.jar which was included as part of a linked library project as well as part of the main project itself.

Error Dx UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/content/ModernAsyncTask$WorkerRunnable;

Problem went away after removing the android-support-v4.jar file from the build path for the main project. Don't think I came across this as possible cause to the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project » Properties » Java Build Path » Libraries and remove all except the "Android X.Y" (in my case Android 1.5). click OK. Go to Project » Clean » Clean projects selected below » select your project and click OK. That should work.

It is also possible that you have a JAR file located somewhere in your project folders (I had copied the Admob JAR file into my src folder) and THEN added it as a Java Path Library. It does not show up under the Package Explorer, so you don't notice it, but it does get counted twice, causing the dreaded Dalvik error 1.

Another possible reason could be package name conflicts. Suppose you have a package com.abc.xyz and a class named A.java inside this package, and another library project (which is added to the dependency of this project) which contains the same com.abc.xyz.A.java, then you will be getting the exact same error. This means, you have multiple references to the same file A.java and can't properly build it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I'm using the ADT 20.0.3.

Steps I followed  to resolve this.

Remove all the jar in project/lib folder and reference them as external jars.
Check android dependencies/reference libraries in project for duplicates,

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with this problem when using Sherlock ActionBar library in my project. You could do the following step, it's work for me.

Right click to your project, select properties.
A dialog will show up, select 'Java build path' on the left menu.
Remove 'Android dependencies' and 'Android private libraries' on the right panel then click OK
Clean your project (select menu Project --> Clean)
Right click your project, select Android Tools -> Fix project properties
Clean project once again.
Restart your computer
Open eclipse and Export apk
Hope that will help you.